# Defining equations for simplify in a loop (Maple)

Tags: maple

I am starting to get used to Maple. I have an old copy of it (Maple 7). I am trying to simplify an equation using the simplify command by typing something like this:

```
simplify(eqn1, {x[1]^2+y[1]^2 = 1});
```

I want to make life easier for the case when I have several equations in my equation expression of simplify (or other maple commands). I want something like this:

```
simplify(eqn1, {for i from 1 to 10 do: x[i]^2 + y[i]^2 = 1 end do:})
```

I don't know if this is possible. So I am asking here if someone knows if something like this is possible in Maple.

Jose

Answer (score 0):

Try it as,

```
simplify( eqn1, { seq( x[i]^2 + y[i]^2 = 1 , i = 1 .. 10 ) } )
```

Comment: I was thinking of defining an array say array(1..10). and then do a for loop and defining the element of this array as x[i]^2+y[i]^2=1 and then do a convert(array,'set')